# After submitting form method="post", request.body is undefined

Tags: forms, express, post, http-post

I am building a website using Express and mySQL.

I want to display items by price and stock using range bar and submit button (form method="post")
However for some reason, request.body is undefined even though I can find Form data when I submit.
Can you please help me out ?

-html-

```
  <form action="/product_list" method="post" id="stock-range">
          <label for="stock-range-bar">Stock</label>
          <input
            type="range"
            class="slider"
            id="stock-range-bar"
            name="stock_range_bar"
            step="100"
            min="100"
            max="5000"
            value="100"
          />
          <div class="range-btn">
            <p><span class="stock-ranged"></span></p>
            <input class="pay-btn" type="submit" value="Search" />
          </div>
        </form>
```

```
productController.post("/product_list", (request, response) => {
  if (request.body) {
    let stockData = request.body;
    console.log(stockData);

    getProdcutsByStockRange(stockData).then((products) => {
      response.render("product-list.ejs", { products });
    });
  }
});
```

stockData is undefined here... and I am using this middleware!

```
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
```

I tried to use body parser but it didn't work :(`your text`

Comment: Did you use the `express.urlencoded()` middleware before the routes? Show us a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example